# Get Kafka consume time for each group

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to get the consumed time for each message by each group in Kafka, but I don't want the committed time that is persisted in consumer_offsets topic, because it is possible that message is consumed but is not committed and I want the consume time not committed time.


In nutshell, I need the consumed time for each message by each group.

Is there a way to get this time?

Comment: Kafka cannot know that, you'll have to implement some logic in the consumers.